# Portfolio turnover

Tags: portfolio-management, portfolio-optimization, portfolio

Really easy question, but I am having doubts. If you want annual turnover, and you have monthly weights, wouldn't you just do in excel:

{=ABS(CurrentMonthsWeights-LastMonthsWeights)*12}  for each month and then just do average over the 12 months to get the annual turnover?

Comment: Do you honestly expect people to know what you have in those two rows in your spreadsheet?

Comment: @will sorry. I fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this:  Let's say you sell 100% of asset A and buy 100% of asset B.  Most people would consider this 100% turnover, not 200%.  Therefore you want to take the sum of the absolute difference in weights and divide that by 2.

I suggest a few changes to your formula.  First, importantly you would take 
SUM(ABS(CurrentWts - LastWeights))/2 for each month.  Note the SUM function and  I'm dividing by 2 instead of 12 because of the first point in my response.  Then you would SUM your results for 12 months.